# std::map and dynamic declared variable throws an exception

Tags: c++, dictionary, exception, dynamic, static

I have a class with a dynamic declared variable ("new") and this class is included in a map. During program startup and initializing the map, "delete" in class destructor throws an exception.

I traced it and during initialization of the static map, it is running both constructor and destructor. Maybe code will be more understandable (all is declared inside class `CTDlg`):

.h file

```
protected:
    class CToolTipBanner //: public CObject
    {
    public:
        CString m_csToolTipMsg, m_csBannerMsg;
        CToolTipCtrl *m_pToolTip; //CObject child is not possible to add to std::map directly

        CToolTipBanner(CString csToolTipMsg, CString csBannerMsg) : m_csToolTipMsg(csToolTipMsg), m_csBannerMsg(csBannerMsg) //konstruktor
        {
            m_pToolTip = new CToolTipCtrl;
        }
        ~CToolTipBanner()
        {
            delete m_pToolTip;
        }    
    };

static std::map<int, CToolTipBanner> mapToolTips;
```

.cpp file

```
std::map<int, CTDlg::CToolTipBanner> CTDlg::mapToolTips
{
    { IDC_BUTTON, CTDlg::CToolTipBanner(L"Toto je banner editu...", L"Edit Tooltip"), },
    { IDC_EDIT, CTDlg::CToolTipBanner(L"Toto je banner buttonu...", L"Button Tooltip"), }
};
```

Comment: `CToolTipBanner` violates the [Rule of Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). It's copyable, and two copies both think they own the same object and will both attempt to delete it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik "Rule of Tree" -> "Rule of **Three**"

Comment: To elaborate on Igor's comment, the code is creating *temporary* `CToolTipBanner` objects, which are *copied* into the map, then the temporaries are destroyed, destroying the `CToolTipCtrl` objects that the map still holds references to. Accessing those objects is then *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I'll point out that if you'd used `std::unique_ptr`, the compiler would have told you about this mistake *and* you wouldn't have to write custom destructors and copy/move constructors/assignments.